# str_ireplace doesn’t works as expected

Tags: php, php-7.3

```
$venue_city = 'PARIS';
$venue_name = 'Le Palais des Congrès de Paris';
```

I create an array with omit words

```
$omit_words = array('d\''.ltrim($venue_city),'de '.$venue_city);
```

`print $omit_words;` gives `Array ( [0] => d'PARIS [1] => de PARIS )`

Now i want to replace `de Paris` from $venue_name by nothing

```
$venue_name_shorten = str_ireplace($omit_words,'',$venue_name);
```

str_ireplace is important because i need insensitive case. Paris could be written with one or more uppercase.

So, nothing happened.

But i know that comes from my $omit_words, because if i replace `'de '.$venue_city` by '`de PARIS'` it works fine.

$venue_city is string type.

Any help will be appreciate.

**EDIT**

$venue_city is not defined like in my question `$venue_city = 'PARIS';` but comes from api data

**EDIT II**

I found !! There was a space left before $venue_city

Comment: What do you mean nothing happened?

Comment: Your code works here with this output: `Le Palais des Congrès`. Is it what you expect?

Comment: Works [here](https://3v4l.org/Ajrvj)

Comment: Maybe if you show us the actual code you are using rather than little snippets the issue would become clear

Comment: It's the same code you have in your link, it works when $venue_city is defined `$venue_city = 'PARIS';` but for me $venue_city comes from an api and it's string type

Comment: I suspect you still have control characters in the string. Make an output with echo bin2hex($venue_city) and add the result of your question.

Comment: @jspit `echo bin2hex($venue_city);` returns 205041524953

Comment: I found !! There was a space left before $venue_city

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use trim() to remove all leading and trailing spaces and line breaks from the API data.

```
$fromApi = " PARIS\n";  //example

$venue_city = trim($fromApi);

$venue_name = 'Le Palais des Congrès de Paris';
$omit_words = array('d\''.$venue_city,'de '.$venue_city);  
$venue_name_shorten = str_ireplace($omit_words,'',$venue_name);
```